# How external variables can be passed into the scope of lambda functions?

Tags: python, function, lambda, scope, closures

I want to define a lambda function inside another lambda function, but when I create the inner lambda function, the outer lambda function's argument is said to be undefined, like this.

```
# time, game, players... are defined above this line
result = filter(lambda x: (player == min(players, key=lambda y: time(game, y, x))), words)
```

Then, the x as one of the `time` function's argument is said to be an undefined variable. I searched through StackOverflow and found that I can use a default value to pass x into the scope of `lambda y` by changing it to `lambda y, x=x: time(game, y, x)`.

I am wondering why x couldn't be used in the scope of `lambda y` directly, just like how `game, time()` are used in it. Aren't `game, time, x` all variables outside the scope of `lambda y`? What's the difference between x and these other variables/functions.

Thanks very much!
[image: The error information]

Comment: Could you turn this into a runnable example where we get the same error you do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why you are having the problem. In a minimal example like this:

```
(lambda x: (lambda y: y+x)(3))(2)
```

You get the expected `5`, so there must be something more to what you are doing.

Comment: I just added a pic of the error information. Would it just be some problems with my VS Code editor, since the program runs correctly?

Comment: @tdelaney the first lambda here does NOT return the second lambda - it gets called immediately after being defined, so no, it is not a closure.

Comment: @tdelaney my code runs correctly, although there is that error information in the editor.

Comment: @IgorRivin could you please elaborate more on why the first lambda function gets immediately called? What is the difference between your example and tdelaney's code? Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMa the code is: `(lambda y: y+x)(3))` So, we define the lambda, and call it on the argument `3`. The value of x u(2) sed is gotten from the outer scope.

Comment: I was waiting for OP to post a running example before further comment. But since this solved the problem, I'll just delete my comments.